# vuejs v-model not working on a select when items come from parent through props

Tags: vuejs2

I'm making a simple vuejs component, essentially wrapping a `<select>`:

```
export const SingleSelect = {
    name: "singleSelect",
    template: `
<div>
        <select v-model="selected">
            <option v-for="item in items" v-bind:value="item.code">
                {{ item.Name }}
            </option>
        </select>
        <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span</div>
`,
    props: {
        items: {
            type: Array,
            required: false,
            default: () => []
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            selected: '',
            myItems: [{ code: 'UK', Name: 'United Kingdom' }, {code: 'JP', Name: 'Japan'}]
        };
    }
}
```

the items prop gets filled from the component's parent, and I know this works because I get a list of countries in the dropdown. But the `v-model="selected"` binding is not working. Nothing is displayed in the span under the dropdown, and when I look at the component in Vue Devtools, it says **selected** is undefined.

As you can see I've also tried using a local list of items (myItems in data). This works fine. **selected** is filled when I choose an item in the dropdown and I can see the value in the span below it. But I need the items list to come from outside. What am I doing wrong?
I'm using Vue.js v2.6.10.

Comment: It looks like maybe the parent component isn't providing a `code` property for the array elements. The fact that the dropdown shows the options only verifies that the parent is supplying a `Name` property. Note that the two properties are using different cases. Could it be that the parent is using `Code` instead of `code`?

Comment: Maybe try a computed property: `computed: {
 getItems: function () {
  return Array.isArray(this.items) ? this.items.slice() : [];
 }
}` and change v-for to `item in getItems`

Answer (score 0):

Comment from Stephen Thomas pointed me in the right direction. The parent component was providing a 'Code' property, not 'code' property. A simple case of being insensitive about casing in a case sensitive environment.